# How to make allowed domain dynamic using Scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am practicing web scrapping. I am trying to scrape the websites and wanted to include allowed_domains so that it does not scrape other urls.

```
import scrapy

class SeleniumSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test_selenium'
    allowed_domains=['quotes.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/']
    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            result = {
            'text': quote.css('span.text::text').get(),
            'author': quote.css('small.author::text').get(),
            'tags': quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').getall(),
            }
            print(result)
```

So, I wanted to changes the allowed domain as URL changes in start_url, not with the same domain but the different domain.

Thank You

Comment: I don't know what you try to do but you can try to change `self.allowed_domains` in any function. Maybe it will work. And I don't understand `"as URL changes in start_url"` - you set it at the beginning and later it doesn't change. It is used only in `def start_requests()` to convert then to `Request()`

Comment: So, suppose we have a list of websites that we wanted to crawl. And I wanted to crawl only the website from the list. The crawler crawls various links, outside of the domain. So, I just wanted to crawl the website which is in the allowed_domain. The url might changes after finishing the crawl and so, I wanted to change the domain accordingly.

Comment: if crawler finished then replace domain in code and run it again. You will change `start_urls` directly in code - so you can also change `allowed_domains` directly in code at the same time. I don't understand where is the problem.

Comment: or maybe you read `start_urls` from file? Then you could read `allowed_domains` also from file. And I still don't understand where is the problem.

Comment: eventually you can create function `__init__` which will get urls from `start_urls`, crop domains and put in `allowed_domains`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understand your problem because it is not so big problem to add manually new `allowed_domains` when you add manually new `start_urls`.

But if you want to create automatically `allowed_domains` based on `start_urls`
then you can use `__init__` to get domains from `self.start_urls` and add to `self.allowed_domains`.

```
import urllib.parse

class SeleniumSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'test_selenium'

    start_urls = ['https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        allowed = set()  # `set()` to keep every domain only once

        for url in self.start_urls:
            parts = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
            allowed.add( parts.netloc )

        self.allowed_domains = list(allowed)
```

---

You may use `__init__` to set other values automatically - i.e. to read values from file or database or get from command line.

---

Full working example

```
import scrapy
import urllib.parse

class SeleniumSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test_selenium'

    #allowed_domains=['quotes.toscrape.com']

    start_urls = ['https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        allowed = set()  # `set()` to keep every domain only once

        for url in self.start_urls:
            parts = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
            #print(parts)
            allowed.add( parts.netloc )

        self.allowed_domains = list(allowed)

        for domain in self.allowed_domains:
            print("allowed:", domain)
    def parse(self, response):
        print('parse url:', response.url)

        for a in response.xpath('//a/@href'):
            yield response.follow(a)
        
# --- run without project ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess()
c.crawl(SeleniumSpider)
c.start()
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. Where I can find the information about scrappy with a good example?

Comment: I have no idea. I simply read all official documentation - from first to last page. And later I use Google to find example when I have problem. And sometimes I check source code.

Comment: I keep code from some my answers on GitHub [python-examples](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/) - see folder [scrapy](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/scrapy) and [___scraping___](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/__scraping__) for examples with `requests`,`beautifulsoup`, `selenium` and `scrapy`